# Error while referencing a cell from another sheet in formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The formula in excel is

```
=100/(INDIRECT("'History Data'!B" & M2)-100)
```

here M2 gives the row number in the Column B and that's the reason I am using **INDIRECT** function. Now when I try to write this in VBA, it throws an error and I am not able to find the solution, but I think it's because of the Sheet I am referencing has a space in its name and therefore I need to manipulate single quote **'**  at the beginning and ending of the formula.

I have written this

```
.Formula = "=100/(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "History Data" & Chr(34) & "!B" & M2 & ")-100)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.Formula = "=100/(INDIRECT(""'History Data'!B"" & M2)-100)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately - instead of using INDIRECT, use INDEX - because you already have the sheet name and column letter, INDEX will (1) be less complex to read; (2) run faster; and (3) not be a 'volatile' function - which means that it won't recalculate every time the sheet recalculates. Non-volatile functions only recalculate when one of their precedents changes.

Your formula would look like this:

```
=100/(INDEX('History Data'!B:B,M2)-100)
```

Which means your VBA code would look like this:

```
.Formula = "=100/(INDEX('History Data'!B:B," & M2 & ")-100)"
```

Though I'm not sure what M2 is meant to reference here within VBA - perhaps this should be:

```
.Formula = "=100/(INDEX('History Data'!B:B," & Range("M2") & ")-100)"
```